# Create a static box in LaTeX

Tags: macros, boxes

How can I make a command to automate the creation of a box? This box would enclose texts or statements, questions and the like when the command is used. Example:

[image: command and desired output]

Comment: Perhaps a simple `\fbox` or something more sophisticated using `mdframed`?

Answer (score 6):

Using `tikz`, `mdframed`, `\fbox` and `\framebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,rectangle,rounded corners=4pt,line width =1.5pt,text width=5cm,minimum width=5cm,minimum height=3cm]{#1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\myboxmd}[1]{%
\begin{mdframed}[linewidth=1.5pt]
#1\par
\end{mdframed}
}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1.5pt}
\newcommand{\myboxframe}[1]{%
\framebox[.5\textwidth][t]{#1}
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\mybox{Text is placed here}
\par\noindent
\myboxmd{Text is placed here}
\par
\noindent
\myboxframe{Text is placed here}
\par
\noindent
\fbox{Text is placed here}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: when i compile this it gives me this error "! LaTeX Error: File `mdframed.sty found".

Comment: @kayla: Did you install `mdframed`?

Comment: i tried to install in terminal Ubuntu by `tlmgr install mdframed` but it says:                                      " No command `tlmgr` found, did you mean:                Command `vlmgr` from package 'qdbm-util' (universe)   Command 'rlmgr' from package 'qdbm-util' (universe)    tlgmr: command not found".

Comment: @kayla: Search this site for installing such packages. I think you are using a tex distribution that came with your OS and not texlive. Refer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution/55473#55473 also

Comment: I installed Tex Live 2009/Debian kpathsea version 5.0.0 in ubuntu 1204. How should i properly make the code above compile..

Comment: is there another way of creating the command without using the package mdframed?

Comment: @kayla Search this site for information on installing texlive/packages in ubuntu. The above code contains other methods too. Only `\myboxmd` uses `mdframed`.